# Spinnaker UI configuration

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

Can someone please tell me why am I getting this ? I have successfully added the AWS account.

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://x.x.x.x:9000/spinnaker/credentials"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://.xx.x.x.x:9000/spinnaker/webhooks/preconfigured"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://x.x.x.x:9000/spinnaker/applications"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `/spinnaker` in the path seems a bit extra and might be the cause of the 404 errors. 
Have you manually added that in Deck/other spinnaker configuration?